# How to wrap a continuous text in a cell in Outlook?

Tags: html, outlook

I have table of width 700px and have 6 columns in it. The last column`<td>` has a continous text of around 1000 characters. I have specified the width of first 5 columns to 100 px each and the last column takes 200px itself. Due to large number of characters in the last column, the width of previous column reduces and text in last column is not getting wrapped.

Before this I have tried using thead but `<th>` width could not be set. I tried giving width in style and outside style, tried giving width with percentage and pixels as well. Nothing is working.

I tried using these in `td`:

```
width="200" style="width:200px"
```

and

```
style="20%"
```